# GIT plugin installation in eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, git

I have GIT plugin folder which contains jar files. But don know how to install in in eclipse.Please help me.

Comment: Why woudn't you install from repository or use Eclipse Marketplace?

Comment: yes, as @AleksandrKravets suggests, click Help-> Install new Software in Eclipse and search on the web for the url to the plugin.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try installing EGit from the Eclipse marketplace. A helpful tutorial for this can be found [here](http://obscuredclarity.blogspot.com/2011/04/install-egit-for-eclipse.html).

Once EGit is installed, you can clone a remote git repository and import it into Eclipse.

Answer (score 1):

You should probably go to Help / Install New Software... in the top menu in Eclipse. Then, add a new repository giving the path to the P2 repository for eGit.

Answer (score 1):

It's a better way to install GIT plugin using repository way. 
By the way, if you have the GIT plugin folder, you can just copy the features and plugins directory to the eclipse install directory and restart your eclipse.